# How can one eliminate redundant, repeated HTML tags via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML that comes back from another process looking like this:

```
Lorem <i style="color:blue;">
<strong>ipsum</strong>
</i>
<i style="color:blue;">
<strong> </strong></i>
<i style="color:blue;">
<strong>test</strong>
</i> dolor sit amet
```

Note that basically every element (where a word, group of punctuation, or group of whitespace constitutes an "element") has its own set of identical tags wrapped around it. I am trying to find a way in Javascript to simplify it back to this:

```
    Lorem <i style='color:blue;'>
<strong>ipsum test</strong></i>
 dolor sit amet
```

It seems at once both simple and complex. My brain is fried from a full day of power-coding, so I'm not coming up with any creative solutions.

Superthanks!

Comment: what wysiwyg is it coming out of?

Answer (score -1):

How about

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vgnxH/)

```
var str = 'Lorem <i style="color:blue;"><strong>ipsum</strong></i><i style="color:blue;"><strong> </strong></i><i style="color:blue;"><strong>test</strong></i> dolor sit amet'
var d = document.createElement('div');

d.innerHTML= str;
var italics = d.getElementsByTagName('i');

var text  = str.substring(0,str.indexOf('<i'))
text += '<i style="color:blue;"><strong>';

for (var i=0;i<italics.length;i++) {
  text += italics[i].textContent;
}
text += '</strong></i>';
text += str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('>')+1);
    console.log(text)
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=text;
```

Answer (score -1):

// You have to be really sure of the source:

// (the lines in the string are broken for posting)

```
var s= 'Lorem <i style="color:blue;"><strong>ipsum</strong></i>'+
'<i style="color:blue;"><strong> </strong></i><i style="color:blue;">'+
'<strong>test</strong></i> dolor sit amet';

s= s.replace(/<\/strong>\s*<\/i>\s*<i[^>]+>\s*<strong>/g, '');



//  returned value: (String)
Lorem <i style="color:blue;"><strong>ipsum test</strong></i> dolor sit amet
```

html:
Lorem   **ipsum test**  dolor sit amet